# Open a pdf from the Help menu in a RCP application

Tags: plugins, swt

I included a HELP_CONTENTS action from the ActionFactory in my RCP application but I would like to open a PDF file when I call it in the application and not the normal xml file. Is that possible? I didn't find any examples online.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `HelpContentsAction` then you'll get Eclipse help. If you want to display your own file then create your own action (you can reuse the icon and text if you want to).

Use [`IWorkbenchPage`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage.html).`openEditor(IEditorInput input, String editorId)` method to open PDF file:

```
org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile workspaceFile;
java.io.File externalFile;

//PDF in workspace
IEditorInput input = new FileEditorInput(workspaceFile);
//or external
IFileSystem fs = org.eclipse.core.filesystem.EFS.getLocalFileSystem();
IFileStore fileStore = fs.fromLocalFile(externalFile);
input = new FileStoreEditorInput(fileStore);

IWorkbenchPage page =
  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
page.openEditor(input, IEditorRegistry.SYSTEM_EXTERNAL_EDITOR_ID);
```